# Turn off show-trailing-whitespace in Echo Area

Tags: hooks, whitespace, echo-area

When I run

```
(setq-default show-trailing-whitespace t)
```

on startup, the Echo Area is affected. I can usually turn this off with hooks, e.g.

```
  (add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook
    (lambda () (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil)))
  (add-hook 'messages-buffer-mode-hook
    (lambda () (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil)))
```

However, I can't seem to find a suitable hook in this case. I'm used to inspecting modes of a buffer with `C-h m`, but the Echo Area disappears when clicked with a mouse or typing resumes.

The only Echo Area hook I can find mention of doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
  (add-hook 'echo-area-clear-hook
    (lambda () (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil)))
```

Defaulting `show-trailing-whitespace` to `nil` does turn off trailing whitespace showing in the Echo Area, but would necessitate manual enumeration of all modes in which to turn it on.

How can one disable show-trailing-whitespace in the Echo Area if the setting is defaulted to true?

Answer (score 0):

The following solves the problem:

```
(with-current-buffer " *Echo Area 0*" (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil))
```

I'm not yet sure how robust/permanent this is; i.e., whether "*Echo Area 1*", "*Echo Area 2*"..., "*Echo Area *n**" might eventually be created and need similar treatment.